# Replace all pixels of a particular color in a C++ matrix class

Tags: c++, opencv

1) I have a Matrix class

```
Mat src = imread("/pic.png", 0)
```

http://i1265.photobucket.com/albums/jj502/anizilla/demo_result.png

I want to replace all the white pixels in the above given image to black.

Is there a way to replace all the pixels with a particular RGB value with another?

2) When I use -

```
src.col(0).row(0)
```

I get the proper values. Is there any way to extract value of each RGB channel?

3) When I use -

```
src.at<Vec2b>(0,0)[0];
```

I get garbage values (like `.` and `!`). I get garbage value if I use `<Vec2d>`

But. When I use

```
src.at<Vec2s>(0,0)[0];
```

I get proper value for channel 0, and,

```
src.at<Vec2s>(0,0)[1];
src.at<Vec2s>(0,0)[2];
```

returns garbage numbers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is very simple if you do it right.

1. Use explicit template instantiation, e.g.

   ```
   Mat3b src = imread("/pic.png", 0);
   ```
2. Use iterators:

   ```
   for (Mat3b::iterator it = src.begin(); it != src.end(); it++) {
       if (*it == Vec3b(255, 255, 255)) {
           *it = Vec3b(0, 0, 0);
       }
   }
   ```

Sorry, the first proposed solution (`src.setTo(newMat, (src == old));`) only works with single-channel matrices.

Comment: ypnos, My image is of Mat class. How do I convert Mat src to Mat3b src?

Comment: ypnos, It throws an error "error: no match for ‘operator==’ in ‘src == old’"

Comment: Make sure that you use Mat3b to make == work. You can just write Mat3b src2 = src; Or make src a Mat3b directly as in my example.

Comment: Please post code so that I can try it. I use code like that in my own projects, so in general I know that it works.

Comment: #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
Mat3b src3 = imread("/home/anirudh/demo_result.png", 0);
Vec3b old1(0, 0, 0);
Vec3b new1(255, 255, 255);
src3.setTo(new1, (src3 == old1));
}

Comment: Sorry, there is indeed the right overload missing, maybe I file a feature request for it. Sorry! I will write down a nice loop for you in a sec.